# Amchart Clicklabel event not working

Tags: javascript, legend, amcharts

I m fairly new to Amchart library and facing a problem with clickLabel event of legend.

here is the Javascript code I have tried:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "legend": {
    "horizontalGap": 10,
    "maxColumns": 1,
    "position": "right",
    "useGraphSettings": true,
    "markerSize": 10,
    "listeners": [{
      "event": "clickMarker",
      "method": function(e) {
        document.getElementById('clicked').textContent =
          e.dataItem.title + ' - marker status before toggle: ' + e.dataItem.hidden;
      }
    }]
  },

chart.legend.addListener('clickLabel', function(event) {

document.getElementById('clicked').textContent =
          e.dataItem.title + ' - marker status before toggle: ' + e.dataItem.hidden;

});
```

here is Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Shivin15/15k53omf/2/

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set [textClickEnabled](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend#textClickEnabled) to `true`.

Check the updated example here: http://jsfiddle.net/15k53omf/3/

Comment: But this overrides the usual behaviour of legend label click of hiding the data. Which can be solved by adding `e.dataItem.hidden = true`. But is there anyway other than this which wont overrides the usual behaviour? Thank you for answer though.